# parse array and pick information that is the same

Tags: loops, multidimensional-array

Hey is an example of an array return from my soap response (i have no control over webservice)

```
[Names]
 [Name]
  [ID] => GH01
  [First] => Greg
  [Last] => Hobb
  [DateAvailable] =>12.04.2011
  [Contactable] => true

 [Name]      

  [ID] => JM01
  [First] => James
  [Last] => Murr;
  [DatesAvailable] => 12.04.2011
  [Contactable] => true

 [Name]
  [ID] => GH01
  [First] => Greg
  [Last] => Hobb
  [DateAvailable] => 13.04.2011
  [Contactable] => true

 [Name]
  [ID] => JM01
  [First] => James
  [Last] => Murr;
  [DatesAvailable] => 13.04.2011
  [Contactable] => true
```

I cannot suitable form a loop that will take each name and group together the available dates. feeling so stupid. seems simple but i cannot get my head around it. perhaps one of your formula gurus can put me in the correct direction.

the code to get the object is as follows:

$result->Names;

how i would like to display:

Name: Greg Hobb
Dates Avaiable: 12.04.2011 - 13.04.2011

hope that makes sense, i understasnd how to display them, just not grab them in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the way you are implementing your array/data is unnecessary and overcomplicated. You have two array elements that are the same, except the date, so that you can take the two DatesAvailable (a start date and end date) and put them together to make your actual DatesAvailble.
In your Name array, just put a startDate and endDate field. That way each element is a different individual holding all data you need.

Here's some real choppy code (whipped it up quickly) of how you could take this, and create a new array like the one I described above:

```
$newArray; $flag; $num;
for($i = 0; $i < count($Names); $i++)
{
    $flag = false;
    for($c = 0; $c < count($newArray); $c++)
    {
         if($names[$i][$ID] == $newArray[$c][$ID])
         {
              $newArray[$c][$endDate] = $Names[$i][$datesAvailable];
              $flag = true;
              break;
         }
     }
    if(!$flag)
    {
         //create a new element in $newArray. set ur ID, contact fields, etc.
         $newArray[count($newArray)][$startDate] = $names[$i][$datesAvailable];
     }
 }
```

Hope this is of any help ><

Comment: yeah shocking how the soap response is laid out. hurts my head

Comment: lol, no crap. if you can't change it, i'll try to write up a loop for ya XD

Comment: if u wouldnt mind giving it a shot. see what you have to offer. i tried something where i made a varible to the current id, then loop until the variable was the same, add it to an array. but i couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Sure thing. Haven't tested, and it might be sloppy, but I hope it helps ya